# How to initialize variables from list in Java?

Tags: java, list, variables, initialization

Suppose that I have created a list of names, eg:

```
Martin 
Paul 
Diego 
Damian 
etc.
```

And I need to initialize respectively, for example (psuedocode):

```
Martin int = 0;
```

And you create them an Output same for all, which is (psuedocode):

```
System.out.println (Martin + "Martin foundn";
```

How to do this automatically?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a `HashMap`, which maps keys to their values.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Martin", 0);
// etc
System.out.println(map.get("Martin"));
```

You can see [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for what you can do this with, but this is the class you will need specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You could define them as an Enum with (hopefully immutable) behaviour:

```
enum Person {
    MARTIN {
        public String pName() {
            return "something here";
        }
        public int pNumber() {
            return 0;
        }
    },
    PAUL {
        public String pName() {
            return "something else";
        }
        public int pNumber() {
            return 1;
        }
    };

    public abstract String pName();
    public abstract int pNumber();
}
```

Comment: @Unihedron: now in uppercase,

Comment: This works and could be what OP wants if they're looking for immutable behaviour.